# Putting space between bars using bar function

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I am try to plot 16 bars, 8 of these belong to one group. I want to give this group the red color, the other 8 belong to another group which is given the blue color. I would like to arrange the bar in pairs, each pair containing one from the red group and one from the green group. I have tried the following:

```
bar(num1,info(1:2:end);
bar(num2, info(2:2:end);
```

in which `info` contains 16 values I want to plot, `num1=1:2:numel(info)` and `num2=2:2:numel(info)`. If I do it this way, all the bars are placed adjacent to their neighbors and there are no gaps between bars. Ideally, to improve visualization, there should be space in between pairs but no space within a pair. For instance, `bar1bar2 <space> bar3bar4 <space> bar5bar6<space>`...

Could someone help me with this spacing issue? Thank you so much!

Comment: `num1=1:numel(info)` should be `num1=1:2:numel(info)` right? otherwise, in the first `bar` command, the first and second arguments don't have the same size.

Comment: sorry, that's correct. I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [docs for bar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html). You can reshape `info` to 2xN (instead of its current shape 1x2N) and then use a single `bar` command to plot the 2 series, and it will take care of the spacing.

See this image from the docs:
[image]

If you want to keep doing it your way, you could just tweak `num1` and `num2`:

```
N = numel(info) / 2;
num1 = (1:N) * 3;
num2 = (1:N) * 3 + 1;
```

Comment: quick follow up question: I'm trying to put error bars on to the graphs. Using the method from the Mathworks doc, I reshape the info into 2xN. However, when I do `errorbar(info,info_errors,'r.')` I get error bars in between two bars instead of being on the bars themselves. Any suggestions?

Comment: errorbar does something else when given matrices as input (different above and below errorbars). So either switch to the second method (and use errorbar twice, once with num1 as X, once with num2 as X), or take a look at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10803-barweb--bargraph-with-error-bars-